# When we breathe through our noise, do the sinuses play any significant role in inspiratory or expiratory flow?

Tags: sinus

I am interested in how air comes into the body through the nose and the degree to which obstructions in the sinuses could affect one's ability to breathe.

I have researched this a bit and I found that there are four sinuses:
[image]

But I could not determine whether there is significant airflow through them. This passage seemed relevant

> Nasal passage is connected to sinus air pockets through an opening called ostia. Airflow in the human nasal cavity has been extensively studied using fluid dynamic simulations. We refer the reader to [11] and references there on. A number of studies have simulated airflow in both nasal passage and the sinuses [10, 12–24]. Xiong et al [12] simulated nasal airflow at 21 L/min in a normal healthy subject and found very little flow between the nasal passage and the sinuses. At the frontal sinus ostium they observed a limited flow rate of 0.014mL/s during inspiration and 0.018 mL/s during expiration. Zhu et al. [20] evaluated post-surgical airways after uncinectomy and bilateral inferior turbinate reduction and noticed that the surgery that aimed to affect flow partitioning also increased sinus ventilation in only one respiratory phase. The effects of surgery on altering nasal airflow is a complex realm and are not completely understood. Also, these studies do not sufficiently describe airflow in the sinus.

Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4889048/

Does anyone happen to know whether any of the sinus cavities play a meaningful role in influencing air flow volume during inspiration or expiration? In other words, if any of the sphenoid, ethmoid, frontal, or maxillary sinuses are obstructed due to something like mucous production, to what extent would it influence the volume of air one is capable of breathing in or out?

Comment: You might want to read up on empty nose syndrome. Only loosely connected, but it seems to demonstrate that the anatomy of the nasal cavity can be very relevant to air flow.

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks, will check it out!